# Tab close detection- explicit vs implicit

Tags: javascript

I am making a test platform

Is there a way we can differentiate if the tab closed by itself ( due to system shutdown/network error) and whether if the user closed the browser.
T

Comment: unclear how a network error closes a tab. But JavaScript does not give much detail on what causes onpagehide or onclose to fire.

Comment: You would need to have some kind of `setTimeout()` that functions as a "heartbeat" sending you data actively to validate that the user has the tab open and active if you really want to verify it.. `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }` will fire before they close the tab, or the browser, and you would need to build in assumptions that if the heartbeat stops it means something else happened to close the tab/browser.